# How to forcibly flush Internet accessible status (NlaSvc) of Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, connection, internet-connection

I can access the Internet actually, but there is an Internet inaccessible icon in the tray. According to my search, this tray icon is related to the service `NlaSvc` (Network Location Awareness). The service is running, and I never modified any key-value pairs in the registry of `NlaSvc`, and I can actually get HTTP 200 response with and without system HTTP proxy from the IPv4 and IPv6 connection status detection URL inside `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`, aka the following URL:

- http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt
- http://ipv6.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt

If `NlaSvc` thinks the Internet is inaccessible, there are other inconvenient things such as when trying to add another language to Windows,

[image: add another language from Settings]

I am notified that I'm offline,

[image: I'm notified that I'm offline]

so that I'm prevented from adding another language. But actually I can access the Internet.

So how to forcibly flush Internet accessible status (`NlaSvc`) of Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like it can only be solved by disable the network adapter then reenable it.

For me, I executed such commands in an elevated PowerShell, then my issue got solved.

```
$ifAlias = (Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 0.0.0.0)[0].InterfaceAlias
netsh interface set interface $ifAlias Disable
netsh interface set interface $ifAlias Enable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).